# Dont understand this regex-behaviour /^(www\.)?([a-z0-9\.\-]{1,})\.{1}[a-z]{2,63}$/i

Tags: php, regex, dns

I wrote this regex to match domains

```
/^(www\.)?([a-z0-9\.\-]{1,})\.{1}[a-z]{2,63}$/i
```

but I dont understand why I match this

```
www.mcdonalds
```

I tested it here: [PHP Live Regex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/) with preg_match() and got

```
array(
    0=>www.mcdonalds,
    1=>,
    2=>www
)
```

The regex obviously ignoring www. at start and match www. in that part

```
([a-z0-9\.\-]{1,})
```

Can someone explain me this behaviour?

Comment: `(www\.)?` is optional, and matches nothing; `([a-z0-9\.\-]{1,})\.{1}` matches `www.` and `[a-z]{2,63}` matches `mcdonalds`.

Comment: (OT: `{1}` is entirely superfluous, and `+` is usually used instead of `{1,}`.)

Comment: But the question is why is (www\.) matching nothing. This is what I dont get.

Comment: @masatar Because of the `?`.

Comment: @Biffen But it is obviously there.

Comment: @masatar Sounds like a regex tutorial would be in place. Yeah, it’s there, but the whole regex wouldn't match if group 1 was ‘used up’ to match `www.`. Regex is smart like that.

Comment: @masatar Just because `www.mcdonalds` has `www.` in it does not mean that the pattern `(www\.)?` has to match.  The `?` makes this group _optional_, and there is a way for the rest of the pattern to match your string.

Comment: With that comma in your input string, it shouldn't be matched at all.

Comment: @Biffen check the first matched group in the OP's PHP output.

Comment: @revo That Comma I put it manually, because I tried it to look like a array-syntax. Sry for that confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your pattern, with the parts matching `www.mcdonalds` highlighted:

```
^(www\.)?([a-z0-9\.\-]{1,})\.{1}[a-z]{2,63}$/i
           ^^^ www         ^.    ^^^ mcdonalds
```

Your question also took me by surprise, and the initial `(www\.)` is not matching to `www.mcdonalds`.